# Using arguments passed to the linker at the level of LLVM optimization (LLVM-passes)

Tags: linker, arguments, llvm

Can I see/access the list of arguments passed to the linker at the LLVM-pass level?

For example, if I run a compilation with the following parameters:

> clang a.cpp b.cpp -o result -std=c++11 -lstdc++ -lm -Wl,someArg1,someArg2 -mllvm -MyPass

in my LLVM-pass (MyPass) I want to see (and to use) a list of arguments: stdc++, m, someArg1 and someArg2

How to do this and what classes and methods store this information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way how LLVM pass could see the cmdline arguments. Maybe you could describe why do you need this and there is a possibility that some other way to solve your problem does exist?